# getting error while writing data into partition table in bigquery using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

ERROR--
**400 The field specified for HOUR partitioning can only be of type TIMESTAMP or DATETIME. The type found is: DATE.**

`created table by below SQL command CREATE TABLE dataset.table_name(execution_ts TIMESTAMP) PARTITION BY TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(execution_ts,HOUR);`

---

`Python configuration TIME PARTITIONIING_FILED = "execution_ts" TIME PARTITIONING_TYPE = "HOUR" OUTPUT_TABLE = "table_name$2023081304"`

Trying to fix above error